# Trust a Web App to AWS via a Trust Relationship?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

Instead of setting my node Express app with AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, is there a quick and easy way to assume a role and get credentials based on a Web site's origin?

I know it's possible to do this in a roundabout way with Google Client ID by

1. Authorizing a Javascript origin, e.g. https://example.com
2. Trusting that client ID in an AWS IAM Role

But if you wanted to this without using Google, is there some direct way with AWS?

I.e. allow my app at https://example.com to be able to assume a role via a **Trust Relationship**?

Comment: it depends on how you are hosting your express app. If you're using an EC2 instance, then you can setup a EC2 Role policy, if you're using fargate for instance you could use a task role.

Comment: Assume it's not running on EC2. I want it to work on http://localhost ;)

Comment: The usual way of doing this is through [federation](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/federation/) if you don't want to use IAM credentials in your app.